# vagrant hangs up after fixed port collision

Tags: vagrant, vlad-drupal

I am trying to bring up vagrant on a Windows machine.
It hangs up after

```
Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
```

A part of the debug log is below:

```
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::HandleForwardedPortCollisions:0x44e7760>
DEBUG environment: Attempting to acquire process-lock: fpcollision
DEBUG environment: Attempting to acquire process-lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Acquired process lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Released process lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Acquired process lock: fpcollision
 INFO handle_port_collisions: Detecting any forwarded port collisions...
DEBUG handle_port_collisions: Extra in use: []
DEBUG handle_port_collisions: Remap: {}
DEBUG handle_port_collisions: Repair: true
 INFO handle_port_collisions: Attempting to repair FP collision: 2222
 INFO handle_port_collisions: Repaired FP collision: 2222 to 2200
 INFO interface: info: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
 INFO interface: info: ==> vlad: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> vlad: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
 INFO environment: Released process lock: fpcollision
DEBUG environment: Attempting to acquire process-lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Acquired process lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Released process lock: dotlock
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::PrepareNFSValidIds:0x44431c8>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "list", "vms"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: "vlad_vlad" {efce349f-2b2e-40db-9a14-2298d3024638}
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::SyncedFolderNFS::ActionCleanup:0x435c3a8>
DEBUG host: Searching for cap: nfs_prune
DEBUG host: Checking in: windows
 INFO nfs: Host doesn't support pruning NFS. Skipping.
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolderCleanup:0x4263ca8>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0/powershell.EXE", "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 2
```

I do not have the slightest idea of how to proceed.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After powershell installation vagrant continued with the setup of the VM